jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate bytes
I'm writing a LLM with jax, but I encounter the OOM issue, here's the full error message:
2024-04-06 13:38:06.053927: W external/tsl/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:296] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 15.20GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but this may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path/run_train.py", line 98, in <module>
    train(parser.parse_args())
  File "Path/train_separate.py", line 282, in train
    state, loss = train_step(state,drop_rng,long_feature,labels_phase,integration_timesteps,model_train,batchnorm=args.batchnorm,weighted=args.weighted)
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py", line 166, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 250, in cache_miss
    outs, out_flat, out_tree, args_flat, jaxpr = _python_pjit_helper(
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 163, in _python_pjit_helper
    out_flat = pjit_p.bind(*args_flat, **params)
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 2677, in bind
    return self.bind_with_trace(top_trace, args, params)
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 383, in bind_with_trace
    out = trace.process_primitive(self, map(trace.full_raise, args), params)
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 815, in process_primitive
    return primitive.impl(*tracers, **params)
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 1203, in _pjit_call_impl
    return xc._xla.pjit(name, f, call_impl_cache_miss, [], [], donated_argnums,
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 1187, in call_impl_cache_miss
    out_flat, compiled = _pjit_call_impl_python(
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 1123, in _pjit_call_impl_python
    always_lower=False, lowering_platform=None).compile()
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 2323, in compile
    executable = UnloadedMeshExecutable.from_hlo(
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 2645, in from_hlo
    xla_executable, compile_options = _cached_compilation(
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 2555, in _cached_compilation
    xla_executable = dispatch.compile_or_get_cached(
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 497, in compile_or_get_cached
    return backend_compile(backend, computation, compile_options,
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/profiler.py", line 314, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Path/miniconda3/envs/s5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jax/_src/dispatch.py", line 465, in backend_compile
    return backend.compile(built_c, compile_options=options)
jax._src.traceback_util.UnfilteredStackTrace: jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 16315842560 bytes.

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Path/run_train.py", line 98, in <module>
    train(parser.parse_args())
  File "/Path/train_separate.py", line 282, in train
    state, loss = train_step(state,drop_rng,long_feature,labels_phase,integration_timesteps,model_train,batchnorm=args.batchnorm,weighted=args.weighted)
jaxlib.xla_extension.XlaRuntimeError: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Out of memory while trying to allocate 16315842560 bytes.

I looked up online and found that this could be perhaps because running Jax and Tensorflow concurrently, and I think this message on the top:
2024-04-06 13:38:06.053927: Wexternal/tsl/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:296] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 15.20GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but this may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.

indicates that I'm indeed using tensorflow somewhere.
However, in my environment (conda list):
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu  
appdirs                   1.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     23.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h5eee18b_5  
ca-certificates           2024.3.11            h06a4308_0  
certifi                   2024.2.2                 pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        3.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
chex                      0.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
commonmark                0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
contourpy                 1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
docker-pycreds            0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
einops                    0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
etils                     1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
flax                      0.7.4                    pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.50.0                   pypi_0    pypi
gitdb                     4.0.11                   pypi_0    pypi
gitpython                 3.1.43                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.6                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       6.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jax                       0.4.13                   pypi_0    pypi
jaxlib                    0.4.13+cuda12.cudnn89          pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_0  
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libuuid                   1.41.5               h5eee18b_0  
matplotlib                3.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mpmath                    1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
nest-asyncio              1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.7.0.72                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.0.13               h7f8727e_0  
orbax-checkpoint          0.5.7                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 24.0                     pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    10.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       23.3.1          py310h06a4308_0  
portalocker               2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.14              h955ad1f_0  
pytz                      2024.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
requests                  2.31.0                   pypi_0    pypi
rich                      11.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sentry-sdk                1.44.0                   pypi_0    pypi
setproctitle              1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                68.2.2          py310h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
smmap                     5.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0  
sympy                     1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
tensorstore               0.1.56                   pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
torch                     1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                0.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
torchdata                 0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchtext                 0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2024a                h04d1e81_0  
urllib3                   2.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wandb                     0.16.5                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.41.2          py310h06a4308_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h5eee18b_0  
zipp                      3.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0  

I don't think I have installed tensorflow in my environment, so why am I still having the message reported by tensorflow?
So far I've tried:
adding os.environ["XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_PREALLOCATE"] = "false"
But it didn't worked and I'm still having the exact same message.
Does anyone know what could went wrong? Thanks for the help

It's hard to guess what's happening without seeing your code, but the simplest explanation would be you're trying to run a model that's too big for your hardware.
